# C++ | Matrix adds weird values

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, chess

I'm trying to simulate chess movements, but somehow values out of array size appears inside array.

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong but I cant find a solution.

I have this **example** code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x1,y1;
int main(){
  int n=10;
  int x=5;
  int y=0;
  char tablero[n][n];
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
      tablero[i][j]='.';
      }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        if(j==x || j==y){
            tablero[x][y]='k';
            x1=x-1; y1=y-1; tablero[x1][y1]='x';
            x1=x-1; y1=y; tablero[x1][y1]='x';
            x1=x-1; y1=y+1; tablero[x1][y1]='x';
            x1=x; y1=y-1; tablero[x1][y1]='x';
            x1=x; y1=y+1; tablero[x1][y1]='x';
            x1=x+1; y1=y-1; tablero[x1][y1]='x';
            x1=x+1; y1=y; tablero[x1][y1]='x';
            x1=x+1; y1=y+1; tablero[x1][y1]='x';
        }
      }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cout<<tablero[j][i];
      cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

The code should **should output** this:

```
....xkx...
....xxx...
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

**Instead** of that the **output** is:

```
....xkx...
....xxx...
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
...xxx....
```

How can I fix that?

***P.S. I'm new on this :P***

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to the fact that you're using negative values in your array subscripts.  Because `y==0`, there are some `y1` that will equal `-1` (ie. `y1=y-1` => `y1=0-1` => `y1=-1`).  You should never use negative values in your array subscripts.  Your code will have unexpected behavior when `x==0` or `x==n-1` or `y==n-1` also.

If you replace the block of the if with `if(j==x || j==y)` with the following code, you'll get the expected result.

```
for(int k=0; k<9; k++){
    x1=(x + (k%3) - 1);
    y1=(y + (k/3) - 1);
    if(!(x1<0 || y1<0 || x1 >= n || y1>=n))
        tablero[x1][y1]='x';
}
tablero[x][y]='k';
```

Comment: That is short and nice. +1

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful.